# Hiding the Autogenerateselectbutton on Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a gridview I used to display my data for MS-SQL. I used the autogenerateselectbutton property to select each row so I can display another Asp.net panel. But now I don't want to show the "Select" Column on my Gridview. How do I hide it but still be able to select the row of the Gridview.

I tried to Hide it using:

```
gv_gridname.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

I added the Autogenerateselectbutton on the .aspx page as:

```
autogenerateselectbutton="true"
```

But it fails because it doesn't count the "Select" column as one of the columns in the GridView.
So How do I hide it and be able to use it to select my rows. Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this one :

In your code behind file,

```
int indexOfColumn = 0; //Note : Index will start with 0 so set this value accordingly
protected void gv_gridname_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Cells.Count > indexOfColumn)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[indexOfColumn].Visible = false;
    } 
} 

 protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gv_gridname, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
    }
}

protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv_gridname.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowIndex == gv_gridname.SelectedIndex)
        {
            row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A1DCF2");
            row.ToolTip = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
            row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
        }
    }
}
```

In your .aspx page do,

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_gridname" runat="server" 
             OnRowDataBound="gv_gridname_RowDataBound"
             OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" 
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged">
```

Jquery Script add in your aspx page :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[id*=gv_gridname] td").hover(function () {
                $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("hover_row");
            }, function () {
                $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).removeClass("hover_row");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Add css in your aspx page:

```
 <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        td
        {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .hover_row
        {
            background-color: #FFFFBF;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: This hides the column true...its the same as I did above. But you wont be able to select the row. This is actually a long way to what I did...but performs the same task.

Comment: I think this code will hide the column which you required, by your code it was not possible.

Comment: True it will hide the column and yes I tried it before commenting...But its not doing what I required. I could Hide the Column but now I wont be able to select the row...Please look at How the Autogenerateselectbutton works.

Comment: IF you hiding the  select column than how you  will want to `select` the row? By using any checkboxes for each rows?

Comment: By Highlighting the row. I'm trying to avoid extra controls by hiding it.. So checkboxes wont wont work for me if they'l replace the place of the Autogenerateselectbutton. Thank you

Comment: This is complete solution for what you want.